# Enterprise Territory Management -- Previewing Rule Assignments

Tags: territory-management

**Enterprise Territory Management Issue**

I am currently examining implementing Enterprise Territory Management. I have a Territory structure set up in the `Planning` stage. According to the [implementation guide](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/200/15/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_implementing_territory_mgmt2_guide.pdf) I can preview assigned rules to territories as stated in the document:

> Run account assignment rules for any territory that has rules defined and belongs to a territory
>   model in Planning or Active state. If your territory is in Planning state, running rules lets
>   you **preview** account assignments. If your territory is in Active state when you run rules, accounts
>   are assigned to territories according to your rules.

I currently have a rule set up to assign an account to a territory based on some `BillingState` values. But there is no preview. The account then gets assigned to the territory and shows up on the `Assigned Territories` related list on the `Account` record. It shows up as being in `Model State` value of `Planning`. This to me isn't a preview, I don't want this visible to end users while building it (granted I am on a dev org so it really doesn't matter at this point, but it will when I implement in production).

**Related List on Account Detail page**

[image]

It saves this relationship in a `ObjectTerritory2Association` object. I can not figure out how to delete this declaratively. And if I try and do it in some anonymous apex I get the following error:

> System.DmlException: Delete failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0JB37000000L0DUGA0; first error: INVALID_OPERATION, An object territory association cannot be created or deleted with Territory Assignment Rule association cause.: []

My question here is how am I supposed to test all of these rules that I am creating if I can't even delete the associations to run the rules again? On top of that, why doesn't it show a preview like the documentation says?

Answer (score 0):

When creating the Territory Account Associations, you are required to provide the AssociationCause = 'Territory2Manual'.  Therefore, when you are deleting the same, you must restrict your deletion list to the same criteria [i.e. Select Id, ObjectId, Territory2Id, AssociationCause From objectterritory2association Where AssociationCause = 'Territory2Manual' And Territory2Id In :Territorys]